# Spark adls read from one container and write to another using different SPNs

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

In PySpark, I am accessing ADLS Gen2 using Azure Service principle (SPN). I am using Spark conf to set the SPN credentials.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<application-id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token")
```

The SPNs that I have are granular and provide access on a container level instead of storage account level. Which means that for a container abcd and wxyz (in the same storage account), I will have 2 different SPNs.

When I configure the Spark conf, I can set SPN on a storage account level. How can I set SPN credentials on a container level? My goal is to somehow add the SPN credentials to Spark conf for both containers and perform read/write operations across containers.

The use-case that I have is to read data from one container to write to another container in the same storage account. Since the SPNs are different and I can set only 1 in Spark conf at the same time, I am unable to do it.

Comment: yes, i am using azure databricks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough#--access-azure-data-lake-storage-directly-using-credential-passthrough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have these access details at query level passing relevant options to DataFrameReader:

```scala
def credsFor(tenantId: String, clientId: String, clientSecret: String) = Map(
  "fs.azure.account.auth.type.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net" -> "OAuth",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net" -> "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net" -> clientId,
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net" -> clientSecret,
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net" -> s"https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"
)

val df1 = spark.read
  .format("delta")
  .options(credsFor("<TENANT>", "<APP1>", "<SECRET1>"))
  .load("<CONTAINER1>@<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net/<PATH1>")

val df2 = spark.read
  .format("delta")
  .options(credsFor("<TENANT>", "<APP2>", "<SECRET2>"))
  .load("<CONTAINER2>@<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net/<PATH2>")
```